# "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: %1 n'est pasune application Win32 valide" when installing .exe generated by PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, importerror, qtcore

I got the

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "xxxx.py", line 10, in <module> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: %1 n'est pasune application Win32 valide
```

error while I was trying to install a .exe that was created by PyInstaller. The weird thing is, only I got the error while others installed the software without any issues. How do I resolve this problem?

Re-downloaded and re-installed, still got the same problem

Comment: Just a guess: The QtCore may try to indirectly load an external DLL (not part of the executable) like e. g. a VC runtime which is compiled for the wrong OS variant (32 bit instead of 64 or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

... reinstall the PyQt6 python if you use PyQt6 package with this argument *--ignore-installed*:

```
pip3 install PyQt6 --user --ignore-installed
```